# Bash integer expression on IF statement when retrieving free memory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am getting the below error while running the script `memory.sh` script:

```
[root@test tmp]# ./memory.sh
./memory.sh: line 3: [: 2.05028: integer expression expected
 Normal
```

The content of the `memory.sh` script is:

```
[root@test tmp]# cat memory.sh
threshold=80
MEMORY=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}')
if [ ${MEMORY} -gt ${threshold} ]; then
    sudo sync;echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
else
   echo "Normal"
fi
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error on the IF statement comes up when retrieving float values from
the Memory.

The following script casts the float memory value to an integer for the comparison:

```
#!/bin/bash

threshold=80
memory=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}')
castedMemory=$(echo $memory | cut -d'.' -f1)
if [[ "$castedMemory" -gt $threshold ]]; then
    sudo sync
    echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
else
   echo "Normal"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to convert the computation result into integer type to be able to compare it. What about that suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold=80
MEMORY=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print int($3/$2 * 100.0)}')
if [ ${MEMORY} -gt ${threshold} ]
then
    sudo sync;echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
else
    echo "Normal"
fi
```

This does *not* throw an error for me but outputs a friendly "Normal" ;-)